# Nested generator vs nested list comprehension inside generator

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator

I have 2 generators. One has a nested generator, and the other has a nested list comprehension.

```
// list of variables
variables = []

nestedGen = (x for x in (y for y in variables))
nestedList = (x for x in [y for y in variables])
```

Both generators can be simplified to remove nesting, but are they identical in terms of function unchanged?

Comment: Yes, they're identical. The list created by the list comprehension is discarded after the entire expression is completed.

Comment: both will have the same end result, because the inner sequence will be iterated and disposed.

Comment: The difference will be in performance, since the list comprehension has to allocate a list to hold all the results of the generator. Creating the list takes time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference if `variables` gets modified.

Reassigning `variables` won't do anything, because both versions retrieve `variables` up front. The first `for` target in a genexp is evaluated immediately, unlike the rest of the genexp. For `nestedList`, that means evaluating the list comprehension immediately. For `nestedGen`, that means evaluating (but not iterating over) the nested genexp `(y for y in variables)`, and evaluating that evaluates `variables` immediately.

*Mutating* the `variables` list, however, will affect `nestedGen` but not `nestedList`. `nestedList` immediately iterates over `variables` and builds a new list with the same contents, so adding or removing elements from `variables` won't affect `nestedList`. `nestedGen` doesn't do that, so adding or removing elements from `variables` will affect `nestedGen`.

For example, the following test:

```
variables = [1]

nestedGen = (x for x in (y for y in variables))
nestedList = (x for x in [y for y in variables])

variables.append(2)
variables = []

print(list(nestedGen))
print(list(nestedList))
```

prints

```
[1, 2]
[1]
```

The `append` affected only `nestedGen`. The `variables = []` reassignment didn't affect either genexp.

---

Aside from that, there's also a difference in memory consumption, since `nestedList` builds a copy of `variables` with the list comprehension. That doesn't affect output, but it's still a practical consideration to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both expressions will produce a similar result. When the outer generator is enumerated, the inner sequence will be iterated and then disposed.

The difference is that, in the second case, a `list` object will have to be instantiated to hold the sequence of elements and then discarded. This is not a huge penalty, unless you are doing this a lot. The first option is preferred, in the general case.

** Important Note: ***

This would NOT be equivalent if you decide to store the inner sequence in a variable!

```
variables = (y for y in "abdce")
nestedGenList = list(x for x in variables)
nestedGenList = list(x for x in variables)  #// will be empty!

variables = [y for y in "abdce"]
nestedGenList = list(x for x in variables)
nestedGenList = list(x for x in variables)  #// ok!
```

In the first case, the iterator will already be fully iterated after the first use, and when tried to iterate the variable again, it will be empty.